# Processing string with numbers causes 'ValueError: invalid literal for int()' error in Python

Tags: python

So basically we are given a text that looks like this:

```
20
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

It's a 20x20 dimensional square, and you have to figure out the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal) in a grid of positive integers. This is what I have:

```
def main():
  # open file for reading

  in_file =  open ("./Grid.txt", "r")
  dimension = in_file.readline()
  dimensions = int(dimension)
  greatest = 0
  grid = ''
  largest = [0, 0, 0, 0]

  for i in range (0, dimensions):
    grid = grid + in_file.readline()

  grid = grid.strip() 
  grid = grid.replace(" ","")
  i = 0
  j = 0 

  print(int(grid[i]))
  for i in range (0, dimensions * 2 + (dimensions - 1)):
    for j in range (0, dimensions * 2 + (dimensions - 1) - 3):
      if (int(grid[i])*10 + int(grid[i+1]))*(int(grid[i+2])*10 + int(grid[i+3]))*(int(grid[i+4])*10 + int(grid[i+5]))*(int(grid[i+6])*10 + int(grid[i+7])) > largest[0]:
        largest[0] = (int(grid[i])*10 + int(grid[i+1]))*(int(grid[i+2])*10 + int(grid[i+3]))*(int(grid[i+4])*10 + int(grid[i+5]))*(int(grid[i+6])*10 + int(grid[i+7]))

  print(max(largest))    

main()
```

I know it's super complicated but basically, I'm not sure how to make this set of numbers look like a list of numbers (an array)... So I essentially end up having to make the numbers. For example the first number is 02, so I multiple 0 by 10, and add 2... Anyways, the problem is that I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error tells you the exact problem: you're trying to turn a single newline character into an integer. What integer should be represented by "go to the next line"? I don't know, and neither does `int()`, so it crashes.

Comment: Also, your way of constructing the array of numbers is a bit more complicated than necessary. You can initialize `grid` as a list (`grid = []`), iterate over the file directly (`for line in in_file:`) and then do `grid.append([int(item) for item in line.split()])`.

Comment: you need to use `lstrip` to strip leading zeros from string `grid = grid + in_file.readline().lstrip('0')`

Comment: Advice:  With rare exception, a handful of small functions are _vastly_ easier to understand than a single do-it-all monster, because you only have to understand a small portion of the program at any one time.  Also, bugs are fewer and easier to find --- if all file I/O is confined to a single 5-line function, then you know exactly where to start debugging any file-reading problems.

Comment: Please remember to come back and accept the answer if you found it helpful. Otherwise, you should explain why the answer did not help so that we can see how it can be improved.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this line:

```
grid = grid + in_file.readline()
```

Change it to:

```
grid = grid + in_file.readline().strip()  # you must strip each line
```

You need to `strip` each line as you read it, but currently, you're `strip`ping only the final string, which leaves all the whitespace you have in each line present. Eventually, your code tries to convert non-numeric characters (e.g. spaces, newlines) into numbers and runs into the error.

After the fix, running it produces the following output:

```
➜  /tmp  ./test.py
0
1614
```

#### Additional Recommendations

You *definitely* need to make your code more readable before posting. It was painful to look at and even more painful to debug... I almost left it there.

One possible start could be in the complicated for loop. Consider:

```
for i in range (0, dimensions * 2 + (dimensions - 1)):
    for j in range (0, dimensions * 2 + (dimensions - 1) - 3):
        tmp = int(grid[i])   * 10 \
            + int(grid[i+1]) * int(grid[i+2]) * 10 \
            + int(grid[i+3]) * int(grid[i+4]) * 10 \
            + int(grid[i+5]) * int(grid[i+6]) * 10 \
            + int(grid[i+7])

        if tmp > largest[0]:
            largest[0] = tmp
```

**First**, it allowed me to see that the culprit was `int(grid[i+7])` instruction, whereas before it would show the entire line while complaining and was not informative.

**Second**, it does not calculate exactly the same thing twice. It uses a temporary variable instead.

**Third**, you should consider converting your `grid` variable into an actual grid (e.g. an array of arrays). Currently, it's merely a string, so the name is misleading.

**Fourth**, while you turn `grid` into an actual grid, you can use a list comprehension and convert the values into numbers directly, as in this short example:

```
>>> line = '12 34 5 6 78 08 1234'
>>> [int(v) for v in line.split()]
[12, 34, 5, 6, 78, 8, 1234]    # array of integers, not strings
>>>
```

It will save you the conversions before getting to the other parts and validates the data for you in the process while the code is still simpler, instead of waiting to your complicated calculations to blow up.

Comment: The first line *is* a single number, though...and the error message shows that it's not a line with multiple numbers that's failing.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: The OP initially had a comment saying the lone 20 in the first line was "bad formatting" (implying it was an SO thing and not the file), which appears to have been removed now, but makes a difference. The file had been described as a 20x20 grid. I'll look at updating as necessary.

Comment: No, the OP said that the blank line ("gap") between the `20` and the grid was due to formatting.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I think that was an honest mistake, since I never actually saw said 'blank line'.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Please see the re-updated post (removed old content), and consider removing the down-vote. Thanks.